# Getting the error "failed to update user password: unable to open database file:The system cannot find the file specified." while updating grafana.db?

Tags: grafana, admin, change-password

I was suddenly logged out of my Grafana admin account and couldn't log in as it showed "Invalid username or password". Even though I entered the correct password.

I tried following instructions from https://community.grafana.com/t/admin-password-reset/19455/5 to update the password in my grafana.db file. First it showed the error that I was trying to edit a readonly database. Then when I changed the permissions, it is showing the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqnDN.png)

Can you please let me know whats wrong and how can I log in again? If i re- install then all progress will be lost